# using OR in awk

Tags: shell, awk

I use the following two commands to see my tables from binlogs.

```
mysqlbinlog mysql-bin.000016 | awk '/session/,/;/' | more

mysqlbinlog mysql-bin.000016 | awk '/session_log/,/;/' | more
```

How do I see both the table lines in a single statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is:

```
mysqlbinlog mysql-bin.000016 | awk '/session(_log)?/,/;/' | more
```

Use '?' to show that '_log' is option so with or without it.

Comment: This is very useful.
But my table names can be anything. (like abc, pqrst)
And I want to see around 5 tables at a time.

Comment: So use | = or like this: '(name1|name2|name3|name4|name5)'. :-D

Comment: Yes. This is what I was looking for. But is it possible to group the queries of each table together? I mean is it possible to find name1  first and then name2, name3 after that and name4 last?

Comment: No. As far as I know. You may need to select it one by one and combine them.

Answer (score 1):

To group output, how about this:

```
mysqlbinlog mysql-bin.000016 | awk '
   !m { if (match($0, /(name1|name2|name3|name4|name5)/)
           m=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
      }
  /;/ { m = "" }
    m { array[m] = array[m] "\n" $0 }
  END { for (m in array) print array[m] }'
```